# How to delete item from List Object in Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I am Having a employees List in List object(**objListEmp**) as shown below.

```
Dinesh    
Upendra
Chandrakanth(Deleted)
```

My question is now i want to display employees in Combox in windows application which are in active mode i.e.

```
Dinesh    
UPendra
```

my code for binding data in to ComboBox is

```
if (objListEmp != null)
{
    cmbAssignedSelector.DataSource = new BindingSource(objListEmp, null);
    cmbAssignedSelector.DisplayMember = "Value";
    cmbAssignedSelector.ValueMember = "Key";
}
else
{
    cmbAssignedSelector.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

**I Tried As shown below**

```
if (objListEmp != null)
{
    cmbAssignedSelector.DataSource = new BindingSource(objListEmp.Where(x=>x.Value.Split('(').ToString()!="InActive").ToList(), null);
    cmbAssignedSelector.DisplayMember = "Value";
    cmbAssignedSelector.ValueMember = "Key";
}
else
{
    cmbAssignedSelector.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

Comment: There is [`Filter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.filter(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @Sinatr Unfortunately `Filter` property requires filtering support from the `BindingSource` underlying data source. `List<T>` has no such support, neither `BindingList<T>`. Actually the only BCL provided class that supports that is the `DataView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (objListEmp != null)
{
    // To remove Deleted user from list
    var sorted = from employee in objListEmp
                 where !employee.Value.Contains("Deleted")
                 select employee;

    cmbAssignedSelector.DataSource = new BindingSource(sorted, null);
    cmbAssignedSelector.DisplayMember = "Value";
    cmbAssignedSelector.ValueMember = "Key";
}
else
{
    cmbAssignedSelector.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Dinesh
Upendra
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use where clause and mentions predicate which will only take employees which are active (Or you can have any other custom condition depending on your requirement.)

```
 objListEmp = objListEmp.Where(x=>!x.Inactive).ToList();
```

You can also compare string in that case.

```
 objListEmp = objListEmp.Where(x=>x.Status!=="InActive").ToList();
```

Comment: In my list Inactive is a string which i have appended from database.

Answer (score 1):

change this line :

```
 cmbAssignedSelector.DataSource = new BindingSource(objListEmp, null);
```

to

```
cmbAssignedSelector.DataSource = new BindingSource(objListEmp.Where(x=>x.Isactive).ToList(), null);
```

If an IsActive Field is string and you save bool vale in filed like 'True' you need cast befor  like this

```
  cmbAssignedSelector.DataSource = new BindingSource(objListEmp.Where(x=>(bool)x.Isactive).ToList(), null);
```

And if you save 'IsActive ' in a Field you just need compare with String like this :

```
objListEmp.Where(x=>x.Isactive.ToLower()="isactive").ToList()
```